# Crystal Reports sql statement greyed out not working

Tags: crystal-reports

I create a Crystal Report using the Crystal Reports wizard, I select the table from the Access.accdb datasource. I select to display all database fields. I do a Group By on one of the fields, I select to same field as the group by, I select standard on the Report Style and click "Finish".  It then fills in the report with all the fields in the Header and will as the detail portion of the report. I click on the Crystal Report and display the options. Under Crystal Reports > database the "Show SQL Query" is grey instead of Black and can't be accessed. It will only print the header but not the detail.   Can anyone help.

Comment: `Show SQL query` is option is only for viewing the query it can't be used for editing the query. To debug run copy the query and run on database and check the report also check the fields in design

Comment: How can I check the query, it appears that there are no queries giving the table data to the program.  When the Show SQL Query was black, I clicked on it and it gave me the query and I was able to change it. That worked 1 time after that regardless I have not been able to get the detail on the report